# Enemy watches player and shoots but bullets will not project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a 2D topdown game and this script makes an object continuously rotate on a spot to always be facing the player, and continuously spawns bullets in that direction.

The only problem is that, of course, I am stuck on the last detail of making the bullets project when they spawn. The bullets spawn but they just sit there.

If the player runs in a circle around the object, it will spawn a perfect circle of bullets around itself that all just sit there. I commented out a few of my other attempts to solve that problem from searching around that didn’t work to show some of what has already been attempted. Thanks so much in advance!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class sightPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Player;
public GameObject watcherShot;
public Transform watcherShotPoint;
public Rigidbody2D wShotRig;
public float wShotforceRate = 500 ;

public void Start()
{
wShotRig = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() ;
}

void Update () {
Vector3 dir = Player.transform.position – transform.position;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y,dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
StartCoroutine(“WShootEvent”);
}

public IEnumerator WShootEvent()
{
yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
GameObject wShot = (GameObject)Instantiate(watcherShot, watcherShotPoint.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
//    wShotRig.AddForce(wShotforceRate*Vector2.MoveTowards,Vector2.*Time.deltaTime) ;
wShotRig.AddForce(transform.TransformDirection * 50000) ;
//    wShotRig.AddForce(transform.TransformDirection * 50000) ;
//wShotRig.rigidbody.AddForce(swipeDirection * 5);
yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
}
}
```

Comment: What is happening currently with your bullet ? Does it move but not in the correct direction ? Or is it not moving at all ?

Comment: They do not move at all. If the player runs in a circle around the object, it will spawn a perfect circle of bullets around itself that all just sit there.

Comment: Maybe your bullet prefab is not correctly set ? Make sure it has a 2DRigidbody and Set Kinematic is false.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with AI.

Comment: spender ... really :-)  Suggest, in such cases just click "edit" ... as I did.  Cheers!

Comment: I'm just not sure if SO is a venue to "make sense of messy learner code".  OP, you do not include **any sort of screenshot** of your setup, and you do not even **mention your physics situation** ... so, are the bullets `Rigidbody`, or what?  Unity engineering spans vast domains of technology, it's impossible for readers to guess what's up.

Comment: Oh come on, ask a question means try to get an answer. In the time you spent on my post on a site that is largely there to help answer questions not answering a question, you could actually answered 3 others.

Answer (score 1):

After making sure your watcherShot prefab is correctly initialized and set you can try this, I assume you want to shoot in the entity forward direction :

```
public IEnumerator WShootEvent()
{
    // code omitted...

    // projecting the transform forward vector on the 2D xy plane.
    Vector2 fdirection = new Vector2(transform.forward.x, transform.forward.y);
    wShotRig.AddForce(fdirection.normalized * wShotforceRate);
}
```

Your bullet prefab needs to have a 2DRigidbody which is not kinematic to be able to apply force on it, with a low mass and low drag so it should move correctly.

Comment: It did have a rigidbody, however I tried your code and it produced some result. Now the bullets project out of the front of the object while it rotates, but all of the bullets fire directly downward regardless of where the player is..

Comment: Made mistake in the code, I edited it can you try again ?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond the servers were down.. Turns out I made a mistake and the bullet prefab had gravity still on it. That would be why the bullets were moving down. I took that off, and added your new script, now they bullets just spawn around it in a circle and do not move just like it was doing originally...Thanks a lot for the attempt thought! :)

Comment: Oh I just noticed something, try to remove the first line of your function, *yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);*

Comment: Unfortunately, no that does not change anything. I'm starting to think it has something about the way that the rigidbody of shot is being called in. In the inspector of the object with this script on it, the public 'W Shot Rig' that is supposed to call for the bullet keeps on changing it to it's own rigidbody. I'll have to look at it more... Thanks again!

Comment: Jason, this question is a mess :)  You've now said you're using the wrong prefab (or something). Delete the question to avoid time wasting, if it's now pointless.